# Post photo on LinkedIn from local Android

Tags: android, post, share, linkedin-api, photo

I have successfully integrated LinkedIn and share text message by following this [url](http://www.androiddevelopersolution.com/2013/05/linkedin-integration-in-android.html).

I am sharing message like this

```
String share = et.getText().toString();
                if (null != share && !share.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
//                  client.postNetworkUpdate(share);
                    et.setText("");
                    client.updateCurrentStatus(share);
                    Toast.makeText(LinkedInSampleActivity.this,
                            "Shared sucessfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Now what i need to do is to share photo on LinkedIn wall.I have to take this photo from local directory not from server. so I have path like :- /storage/.....

Can any one tell me how to do it.

Comment: In Linked In we can not post photo from local, because in Linked In API there is no method to post photo from sd-card.